# Can someone help me to identify this 6-pin SMD IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount, light

Is anyone able to help me identify this 6-pin SMD IC, or know what it does? I've been googling for it but I'm unable to find it or figure out what it is from the markings on it.

As seen in the pictures the marking on it is TP4122 A3P. It's from an LED driving light. A few of these are burnt in both of my lights, any assistance would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer is likely [TPOWER (源中芯半)](http://tpower-ic.com/), but I can't find anything about this specific chip.